# Open multiple help windows in the same tab page

Tags: vim

When I have a help window open in vim, and I then search another topic in the help, I jump to the new topic (and away from the original one) in the original help window.

Is it possible to simply open a second help window, preferably in a new window split?

I'm used to opening multiple tabs when trouble shooting in my browser, and I feel limited when browsing Vim's help. This is especially the case when I'm reading the help, and then stumble across some vim feature that I wasn't looking for, but sounds interesting/useful.

Of course I've been looking in vim's help documentation for the answer, but come up short...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can prepend `:tab` to commands that split the window to force the new window to be opened in a new tab page:

```
:tab help :tab
```

That said, every jump to a new tag in the `:help` is stored in a `:help tagstack` so it is easy to backtrack with `<C-t>`.

> Of course I've been looking in vim's help documentation for the answer, but come up short...

The feature is introduced in chapter 8 of the user manual:

> You can put ":tab" before any Ex command that opens a window.  The window will be opened in a new tab page.  Another example:
>
> ```
> :tab help gt
> ```
>
> Will show the help text for "gt" in a new tab page.

Comment: Any way to do it in the same window using a split or vsplit?

Comment: @wxz, what do you mean?

Comment: It looks like combining your approach of 'tab help: subject', with the plugin [Tabmerge](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Tabmerge) can get multiple help windows in the same buffer. I'll just need to make some mappings/functions to do it in one step

Comment: "Multiple help windows in the same buffer" makes no sense. Did you mean "multiple help windows in the same tab page"?

Comment: Ah yes, I made a typo. Indeed I meant multiple help windows in the same tab page. I can't seem to edit my previous comment now though (that was my first ever comment, so maybe I'm missing something). Thanks

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I managed to get what I was after (posted as a separate answer). Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer from @romainl, coupled with the plugin [Tabmerge](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Tabmerge), I've got a function that can open multiple help windows in the same tab page:

```
function! NewHelpSplit(subject)
    let current_tabpage = string(tabpagenr())
    " open a help page in a new tab
    :execute ':tab :help ' a:subject
    " merge that tab as a split in current tab (bottom, means the original tab
    " content will be on the bottom, and therefore the help will be on the top)
    :execute ':Tabmerge ' current_tabpage ' bottom'
endfunction
```

Defining a new command:

```
:command -nargs=1 NHelp :call NewHelpSplit("<args>")
```

So to use it to open a new help window on the subject of tabs, even if you already have a help window open, do:

```
:NHelp tabs
```

Comment: Pretty cool. That's what I was asking on the other answer.